# Reload page in IE9 after a few minutes?

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I have a website that is used for check-ins. Unfortunately, the computer is in an area that isn't used often throughout the day, so the website used for check-ins logs itself out after a certain amount of time of inactivity.

The website being used does not have an option to adjust the timeout period.

Is there a way in IE9 to automatically redirect to a new page (or the home page) after a certain amount of time?

The current page should not be refreshed, as it has a check-in number within the URL (something like http://example.org/checkin.aspx?id=123456). So if that page is refreshed, then the check-in happens multiple times (which is undesirable).

Comment: So, you want to navigate to another URL and then back to the original I assume?  You never said if you wanted to return back?

Comment: Not quite. Just to the main page of the check-in site.

Comment: I found a 3rd-party refresher called Yrefresher. It's close to what I was looking for, but only refreshes the page that is open and doesn't redirect or load the homepage.

Comment: WHat's a check in?

Comment: @paradroid: It's not a technical term--it's used to check people in. Similar to what happens at gym where members have to present their membership card to gain access to the facility.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way that I can think of is to create a simple HTML page that loads the site in an iframe. Have this page use meta-refresh to reload every n seconds. Crude, but it will get the job done.

Comment: This assumes programming ability and a server to execute scripts with IIS configured. but +1 as does the job I think.

Comment: I'd rather not depend on a second server for access.

Comment: It doesn't depend on a second server, IIS, or a script. I could slap this up on my local machine in about 2 minutes. Throwing the page in an iframe hardly constitutes "programming". You can Google that in a jiffy. The meta-refresh is a http header... no JavaScript needs to be harmed.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can do this with IE.

Workaround: You could just write a small bat script which opens the site in question and within task scheduler get it to launch at the desired times.

You can then write another script which closes all instances of IE at certain times.

Providing you don't delete your session/cookies on logout I think this will work.

Comment: The check-in site requires a login. Closing and re-opening IE would be the same as letting the site timeout.

Comment: I realize I might not be able to do this natively with IE. I'm certainly open to 3rd-party stuff.